# Windows 7 machine suddenly lost internet/network access but can still ping

Tags: windows-7, networking

I was working on a user's Windows 7 machine. Everything working fine and as normal. Rebooted and suddenly Chrome can't connect to any website at all.

I get the error "Your Internet access is blocked Firewall or antivirus software may have blocked the connection". Windows Network Diagnostics suggests that Windows Firewall is blocking it (it's not) but even after allowing it to confirm a "fix", the issue remains.

What's really odd is that I still have internet/network access. I can ping IPs and domains fine. I can ping servers on the local network fine.

However, with Chrome, Firefox and IE, I can't connect to any website even if I try to go just by IP. I can't even load the router web interface even though I'm connected and have a IP assigned by DHCP.

I can ping the file server but if I try to browse a drive either by hostname or IP I cannot connect to the server.

Zero settings have been changed since this machine was working every day until literally 5 mins before the reboot.

I have checked hosts file and run AV and spyware scans. One odd thing is that I can't open Windows Firewall (when I click it does nothing) and nslookup also fails.

I cannot stop the Windows Firewall service and if I try to open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security I get "There was an error opening the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security snap-in" and "error code: 0x6D9.

The machine is connected by a working ethernet cable.

EDIT: Seems to be a Windows Firewall issue. I can open Windows Firewall in Safe Mode with Networking and turning it off allows everything to work again fine. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any able to open Windows Firewall let alone change the settings with a normal Windows boot.

Comment: It looks that your firewall is blocking HTTP and/or HTTPS but let pings out.

Comment: That doesn't explain nslookup not working not Windows Explorer. And I have no Firewall other than Windows Firewall which, as explained, doesn't seem to work at all at the moment. I just tried to do a System Restore but the machine says it has no restore points :/

Comment: Restart the PC again.

Comment: Have done so about 15 times and counting now.